# collection.find that doesn't match any elements in an array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to avoid having to use another loop to weed out workers who's ID is in my workersThatApplied array. Is there a way to accomplish this in my query?

```
  workersThatApplied = ['ehslj8373d', 'gkjhgjr737d'];

  Workers.find({
    'userId: // only select workers who's id isn't in the workersThatApplied array 
    'Trades': {$exists: true},
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the mongodb not-in [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator:

```
const workersThatApplied = ['ehslj8373d', 'gkjhgjr737d'];
Workers.find({
  userId: { $nin: workersThatApplied },
  Trades: { $exists: true },
});
```